# cakephp 2.4: date change automatically according to different time zone

Tags: cakephp, timezone

Can anyone tell  how can i display date for different time zone (for different countries)?
I am completely unaware of it..
Current server timezone is: Europe/Berlin

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//you can use this api and pass to ip address 
<?php
public function getLocationInfoByIp()
      {   $ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
         $ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));   
     if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null)
     {

       $result['country'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode;
       $result['city'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_city;
     }
      $tags = get_meta_tags("http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=$ip"); 
      $result['ipaddress']=$ipget;
      $result['timezone']=$tags['timezone'];

     return $result;
     }
?>
```

Comment: $ipget ? where this variable comes from?

Comment: pass to ip address   $ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Comment: I put this code in my appcontroller but what what should i do after that? @MukeshKumarBijarniya

Answer (score 0):

you can get time zone via API (based on IP address) at page load time, and store into session or cookies. if no time zone has not found then use default.